# Android Sqlite insert speed when query for duplicates

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

The code below is in an Async task which fetches csv files over the internet before parsing them and adding them to an sqlite database.

As pert of this I need to check, prior to adding any new rows, that they do not already exist in the database.

My problem is that with the duplicate checking code it takes 2.5 minutes per csv file but without the check it takes 6 seconds per file.

Any clues how to speed it up with the duplicate checking, please?

```
  public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //for each csv file
        for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++) {
            get_config("sen" + x + "data.csv");
        }

        return null;
    }



    private void get_config(String siteurl) {

    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        String mfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/HG";
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mcontext);
        String basesiteurl = prefs.getString("site_url", "");


        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(mcontext)) {
            write_alertlog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - No internet connection");
        }else{

            write_alertlog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - Internet connection success");

            String onlineupdateline = "";
            try {

              Random randomGenerator = new Random();
              int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100); //defeat android cache

              DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(basesiteurl + "/csv/" + siteurl + "?unused=" + randomInt);
              HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 8000);
              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 8000);
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
              HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

              BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
              InputStream is = buf.getContent();
              BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


              //reformat csv filename into sensor name for db
              String sensor_name = siteurl.replace("data.csv", "");

                database.beginTransaction();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    //total.append(line + "\n");

                    if (line.contains("<!DOCTYPE")){
                        write_applog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - csv file empty or does not exist: " + siteurl);
                        Log.d("test", "csv file empty or does not exist: " + siteurl);
                        database.endTransaction();
                        is.close();
                        r.close();
                        return;
                    }

                    List<String> singlecsvline = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));

                    //csv date format
                    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
                    Date pi_date = null;
                    try {
                        pi_date = fmt.parse(singlecsvline.get(0).toString().trim());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //database date format
                    fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String db_dateString = fmt.format(pi_date);
                    Date d = null;
                    try {
                        d = fmt.parse(db_dateString);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    long db_dateLong = d.getTime();

                    //check if not in db already and if not add it
                    //this duplicate check makes processing each csv file go from 6 secs to 2.5 minutes
                    sql = "SELECT * FROM sensordata WHERE sensor_date='" + db_dateLong + "' AND sensor_id='" + sensor_name + "'" ;
                    Cursor findrawdata2 = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
                    if (!findrawdata2.moveToFirst()) {
                        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO sensordata (sensor_id, sensor_date, sensor_value, alerted, setflag) VALUES ('" + sensor_name + "', '" + db_dateLong + "', '" + Double.parseDouble(singlecsvline.get(1).toString().trim()) + "', '0', '" + setflag + "');");
                    }else{
                        //Log.d("test", "Not Adding - exists");
                    }
                    findrawdata2.close();

                }//for each line in csv file
                database.setTransactionSuccessful();
                database.endTransaction();

                is.close();
                r.close();
                write_applog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - added sensor " + siteurl);
                Log.d("test", "finsihed adding csv sensor " + siteurl);


            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                write_alertlog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - Internet connection request timed out >6000ms");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                write_alertlog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - Error - " + e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                write_alertlog("AlertService: Fetch csv data - Error - " + e.toString());
            }

        }//have internet connection


        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually loading a row from the database is not necessary if you just want to check if it exists; use something like EXISTS, or a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):

```java
long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database, "sensordata",
                "sensor_date = " + db_dateLong + " AND sensor_id = ?",
                new String[]{ sensor_name });
if (count > 0) {
    ...
```

However, the biggest slowdown comes from searching the rows in the database.
You need to index the search columns to get fast lookups:

```
CREATE INDEX insert_name_here ON sensordata(sensor_date, sensor_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, ive added the databaseutils example however db_dateLong, sensor_name are not both strings[]. db_dateLong is long and sensor_name is string. Is there a way round that?

Comment: You are using it as a string in your query.

Comment: database is int and var is long

Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to String